# How to save fragments in arraylist android

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-activity

I am creating an application in which I need to store all my fragments in `ArrayList`. I am using tab view in the activity and replacing the fragments upon taping different tabs.But every time I click on the tab, its also going to `onActivityCreated`, but instead of this I want to save all the fragments in my `ArrayList` and use them instead.Is there any standard method for this

Answer (score 1):

You can't save `Fragments` or `Activity(s)` in Android. They are internally managed by Android OS or Android `JVM`. If you are using `ViewPager` you can avoid recreating Fragments by settings `setOffscreenPageLimit`.